# Microsoft's implementation of viewstate isn't causing "Confirm Form Resubmission" message to appear, how did they do that?

Tags: php, asp.net, forms, viewstate

My ViewState implementation causes "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog to appear each time I press 'back' button, but when I create test site using microsoft's aspx their viewstate isn't causing such problems...

What should I know to prevent my browser from showing "Confirm Form Resubmission"?

**EDIT**

I've found an interesting resource [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1553589/3814773.aspx), the problem described in terms of browser caching, if the page is cached than it won't make a post at all, now it is interesting how to make my page cachable by default..

Comment: Please provide the code for a test case (example) that you've come across. Any time the page is posted and you try to go 'back' this should happen.

Comment: The problem is that I've developed a framework it has a dozen of classes and it is rather large to post, I'm thinking about other ways of showing the code, but currently no succes

Comment: That's why I asked for a test case -- something that is a proof of concept

Comment: I've found the following post http://forums.asp.net/p/1553589/3814773.aspx that I think might help me, but I can't understand how to mark a page as "cacheable"

Comment: I can give you link to my website and give instructions how to achive the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is interested, the problem is solved when setting the following page heder:

"Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate" it simply caches the page on the client. And this prevents the browser from displaying "Confirm Form Resubmition"

[Here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) is good info about caching the pages on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

One classic trick is to issue a redirect after the post. So, let's say you have a form with a text box and a button:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" onclick="MyButton_Click" 
        Text="Button" />
```

In the event handler of the button, you do something like this:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the value of the textbox and do something with it
    string text = MyTextBox.Text;

    // Redirect to a Thank You page
    Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
}
```

If you want to, you can redirect to the very same page you where standing at, but you will loose all your ViewState.